# <p:selectOneMenu> selected value always null

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces

My goal is to get the selected value of type Sistema, so I can update a datatable and another SelectOneMenu.

Whenever a value is selected the ajax tag behaves correctly, and calls `configura()`, however my `sistemaSelecionado` (wich is an Object in Bean)always return as null to my Backing Bean.

The converter is working fine in another page with the same class Sistema. But it doesn't fire on this specific page.

**This is the xhtml page**

```xml
<div>
    <p:outputLabel title="Sistema"></p:outputLabel>
</div>
<div>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenu"
        value="#{permissaoListBean.sistemaSelecionado}"
        converter="entityConverter">
        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{permissaoListBean.configura}"
            update="selectOneMenuGrupo,secoes"></p:ajax>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{permissaoListBean.listaSistema}"
            var="sistema" itemLabel="#{sistema.nome}" itemValue="#{sistema}">
        </f:selectItems>

    </p:selectOneMenu>
</div>
```

**Here is my Backing Bean**

```java
@Component("permissaoListBean")
@Scope("session")
public class PermissaoListBean {
private List<Sistema> listaSistema = new ArrayList<Sistema>();
//Service das entidades

@Autowired
private SistemaService sistema;

@Autowired
private GrupoService grupo;

@Autowired
private SecaoService secao;

//Objetos da view

private Sistema sistemaSelecionado;
private Grupo grupoSelecionado;
private List<Secao> secaoSelecionada = new ArrayList<Secao>();
private LazyDataModel<Secao> modelo ;


public void populaSistema(){
    listaSistema = sistema.findAll();
}

public void configura(){
    populaGrupo();
    populaSecao();
}

public void populaGrupo(){
    setListaGrupo(grupo.findBySistema(sistemaSelecionado));
}

//dataTable lazyLoad code

//end of lazyload

public List<Sistema> getListaSistema() {
    setListaSistema(sistema.findAll());
    return listaSistema;
}

public void setListaSistema(List<Sistema> listaSistema) {
    this.listaSistema = listaSistema;
}

//getters and setters
```

Comment: The only source of error can actually be just the converter. Did you debug it and checked that it *really* returns the correct object as expected?

Comment: Hello @noone, after debuging I realized that the converter isn't fired when I select a option. Although I have The same SelectOneMenu(same Object, same converter) in another page, and it works just fine. I don't know why.

Comment: Is any request sent at all? Do you have a <h:form> there as well?

Comment: No I don't have a form, just the general <ui:define > wrapping it all.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure now, but I think you need a <h:form> around it, otherwise there won't be a request at all.

Comment: This is why the full but minimal context should be provided...

Comment: You should transform it in an answer, so I can accept it.